# Get a string from a data stream

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api, stream

I am accessing an API through a .NET 3.5 application, and so far my code looks like so:

```
Dim strLink As String = "http://www.google.co.uk"

Dim request As WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://random-web-api/controller/id")

Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()

If CType(response,HttpWebResponse).StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then

    Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()

    ' How do I get the String from the Stream? 

    response.Close()
End If
```

I am able to call the API, and get an OK status, but I don't know how to convert my `ResponseStream` into a `String` in VB?

Comment: What should the stream return, what should it be filled with?

Comment: Aren't streams usually Byte arrays? It'll be filled with `"10"` as a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most easy way I could think of:

```
'Convert stream to string
Dim reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
Dim streamText As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
```

Note: This will only work for ASCII encoding.

Edit, you could add following method to your application, this one allows a encoding parameter.

```
Private Shared Function MemoryStreamToString(ms As MemoryStream, enc As Encoding) As String
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(enc.GetString(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, CInt(ms.Length)))
End Function
```

Above function should be called like:

```
Dim streamText As String = MemoryStreamToString(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Encoding.ENCODINGTYPEHERE)
```

Go here for more information about [Encoding MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

In order to convert a stream to a string you need to use an encoding. Not sure if this is what you're looking for

```
        Dim strReader As New StreamReader(dataStream, Encoding.UTF8)

        Dim yourString As String = strReader.ReadToEnd
```